# Objective C: Assign a value such that all pointers to that variable obtain the new value

Tags: objective-c, pointers

Imagine I define a variable like this

```
NSString * a = @"Hello people";
```

And now I copy the pointer to b so that both a and b point to the location where @"Hello people" is stored in memory (right? Or do I misunderstand how this works?)

```
NSString * b = a;
```

Now I want to change b such that a is also updated with the new value. The following does not work since it will point b to a **new** NSString @"Thanks all"

```
b = @"Thanks all!";
NSLog(@"%@", a); // still "Hello World"
```

but what I want is to **replace** whatever is at the memory location of @"Hello people" so that all pointers to it will update as well.

```
b = ????;
NSLog(@"%@", a); // Whoa, it still points to the same memory location as b!
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you want to use `NSMutableString` instead of `NSString`.

Because an NSString is immutable, when you change the original, it points to a whole new instance. But if you use an mutable version, the pointer remains unchanged even if the contents change.

However - although this will work, it's a bad idea. Such mutability is fragile. For example, if you have any KVO observers on this property, if the string changes, then no KVO notifications are fired.

**Edit**

An alternative is to use multiple indirection:

```
NSString **string;
&string = @"some string";
```

Now you can have:

```
NSString **string2 = string;
```

And changes to string will be propagated to string 2, because although the pointer is the same, the object that it points to will have changed.

Hovewever, you'll need to dereference the pointer to use it, i.e.

```
NSLog (@"String is: %@", *string);
```

or

```
NSLog (@String2 is: %@, *string2);
```

But you still have that mutability issue.

Comment: Hmm ok. But I should in general be able to replace a memory location with something else, right? Or be able to update all pointers from location X to location Y at once? Is there nothing like that?

Comment: But for replacing a piece of memory, you don't need to know what points to that location, right? I want to update an NSDate to the current time. If I do b = [NSDate new]; that will not work. But how should I do it? :-)

Comment: @WillemMulder  Deleted my last comment, and updated my answer with another option.

Comment: Whoah, a pointer to a pointer :-) Well, apparently I need to dive in a little deeper... There is no such a thing as a mutable NSDate, right?

Comment: That is correct; `NSDate` is immutable. But `NSData` is mutable, but that's a different object. There are many such "Class Clusters" in Cocoa that have a mutable and an immutable type; `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSSet`, `NSData`, `NSString`…